# Update ListView after receiving Broadcast

Tags: android, listview

I have an app I am developing that polls a vehicle's sensors via the obd2 port. Everything is going great and now I am adding a new activity that shows which sensors are supported and which aren't.

The issue now is that there is a possibility that a user might start the activity before all the supported commands have been checked, thus the ListView needs to be updated when the variable does change.

Now all the available pids are stored on a variable on the mainview, but once it changes it gets broadcasted and updated on the supportview.

The issue I am having is that it doesn't want to update the listview automatically. I have gone through multiple threads on SF and haven't found a solution thus far. I have tried everything from creating a custom handler and receiver to running it on the UI-thread.

This is the complete activity:

```
public class SupportedView extends ListActivity {
ArrayAdapter<Spanned> mAdapter;
ArrayList<Spanned> commandsList;
private String availpids;

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get extra data included in the Intent
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "ObdReader");

        if (!wakeLock.isHeld()){
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            wakeLock.acquire();
        }

        String pids32 = intent.getParcelableExtra("pids");

        updateList(pids32);
        Log.d("receiver", "Got message: Updated PIDS" );


        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Toast.makeText(context, "Received and tried update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sl_listview);
    //Set fullscreen
    availpids = MainView.pids32_val;
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("pids"));

    updateList(availpids);

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Spanned>(this, R.layout.sllist_item, commandsList);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    //ListView lv = getListView();

}


public void updateList(String listPids){
    commandsList = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<Spanned> tmpEnabled = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<Spanned> tmpDisabled = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ObdCommand Command : ObdConfig.getCommands()) {
        int commandKey = Command.getKey();

        if(commandKey > 0 && commandKey < 999 && listPids != null) {
            boolean isSupported = String.valueOf(listPids.charAt(commandKey - 1)).equals("1");
            if (isSupported) {
                tmpEnabled.add(Html.fromHtml( "<font color=\"green\">"  + Command.getName() + " isn't supported</font>"));
            }else {
                tmpDisabled.add(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"red\">" + Command.getName() + " is supported</font>"));
            }
        }
    }
    commandsList.addAll(tmpEnabled);
    commandsList.addAll(tmpDisabled);
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
    super.onDestroy();
}


}
```

Comment: `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` this should run on the main thread I believe. Use `runOnUIThread()`, put that line inside and see what happens

Comment: where are you registering your Broadcast receiver?

Comment: @Boss Broadcast receiver is at the top of the activity. It is receiving the broadcasts though, have checked logcat and the toast appears. The broadcaster is on the MainActivity.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I have tried this unfortunately. Without any luck. And have also read on 99% of the threads that the broadcast runs on ui by default.

Comment: you are creating new `commandsList` each time when you call `updateList`. Instead add items to the list which should be initialized only once before setting your adapter

Comment: @Boss tried that now with no luck. If I close the activity and start it again it will be updated. If the screen turns off and on again it gets updated. So for some reason it's not refreshing the listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at your 'updateList()' method:

it takes the String with the pids and creates and populates a

> new ArrayList()

named 'commandsList'.

In fact, you are using the same name for two different objects. The other object is the `ArrayList<Spanned>` you declared as a class variable (member) and assigned to be the data source for the `ListView` in your 'onCreate()' method.

I think what you meant to do in your method 'updateList()' was to empty the data source list and then fill it with the pids.

To achieve that, change the method as follows:

```
public void updateList(String listPids)
{
    // empty the data source list:
    commandsList.clear();

    final ArrayList<Spanned> tmpEnabled = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<Spanned> tmpDisabled = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ObdCommand Command : ObdConfig.getCommands()) 
    {
       // keep this part as before ...
    }

    commandsList.addAll(tmpEnabled);
    commandsList.addAll(tmpDisabled);
    // now, you have indeed changed the data set :) 
}
```

In addition to that, in order to make sure that the `BroadcastReceiver` is available when needed, you should register it in 'onResume()' and unregister it in 'onPause()' (the method 'onDestroy()' is not guaranteed to be called).

Comment: Thank for taking the time to respond. I have tried your suggestions but the listview still doesn't get updated while the activity is  shown, only when closing it and opening it again it updates. The broadcast do get received though.

Comment: Although this was not ultimately what solved my problem, it did point me in the right direction indirectly.
It turns out my issue was the message that was sent was the string, and I was receiving it wrong via (getParcelableExtra) instead of getStringExtra. So there was no way for users to find the issue on here without seeing the mainactivity. And Since your answer pointed me in the right direction I am going to accept it since it also fixed another issue I was having.

Comment: happy to help :) but yes, sometimes the reason for unexpected results is that we took some input for granted. Thanks for your feedback!